# $f : S^1 \to\mathbb R$ is continuous then $f(x)=f(-x)$ for some $x\in S^1$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Question is to prove :

$f : S^1 \to \mathbb R$ is continuous then $f(x)=f(-x)$ for some $x\in S^1$

I guess it would be helpful to use intermediate value theorem

Assuming $f(x)\neq f(-x)$ then given any $p\in (f(-x),f(x))$ (assuming $f(-x)<f(x)$) there exists $y\in (-x, x)$ such that $f(y)=p$

I am not very sure of how to use this..

It would be helpful if someone can give some hint which would help me to solve this..

Thank you.

Comment: by the way, from this you can conclude (though its not a perfect sphere)  that on the earth there are two antipodal points that have the same temperature. You can replace temperature also by humidity, air pressure etc. as long as you assume that those quantities are distributed continuously along such crosssections of the earth

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Define $g:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ as $g(t):=f(e^{2\pi it})-f(-e^{2\pi it})$.

Clearly $g$ is also continuous. 
We claim that $g$ is zero at some point. 
If that is true, say $g(t_0)=0$, then it means $f(e^{2\pi it_0})=f(-e^{2\pi it_0})$, hence we get what we wanted.

Suppose $g(t)\neq 0\; \forall\; t\in S^1$, in particular $g(0)\neq 0$. 
Observe that $g(0)=f(1)-f(-1)$ and $g(\frac{1}{2})=f(-1)-f(1)=-g(0)$.
Hence if $g(0)>0$, then $g(\frac{1}{2})<0$, and similarly, if $g(0)<0$, then $g(\frac{1}{2})>0$. 
Thus by the intermediate value theorem, there must be a point say $t_0\in (0,\frac{1}{2})$ such that $g(t_0)=0$, which gives a contradiction.

Observe that in the same way you can obtain not just a $t_0\in (0,\frac{1}{2})$ such that $g(t_0)=0$, but another point $t_1\in (\frac{1}{2},1)$ such that $g(t_1)=0$, because $g(1)=g(0)$.

Note: Instead of defining $g$, you may define, $h:S^1\to \mathbb{R}$, as $h(x)=f(x)-f(-x)$, and follow the same steps as above. The intermediate value theorem can be applied to the function $h$ also, because $S^1$ is a path-connected space.

Comment: simple. perfect!! :P

Comment: Can $f$ be surjective?

Comment: $S^1$ being compact, and $f$ being a continuous function, its image must also be compact and hence bounded. Intuitively you can think of moving around the circle and keeping track of the images of each point. When we move around the circle, say starting at 1 and move in the anticlockwise direction and finally reach back at 1, see what happens in the codomain. You will be starting at $f(1)$, move left or right, or oscillate in the two directions, you may go as far as you can, but finally you have to be back at $f(1)$, which demands that you can't touch $\pm\infty$.

Comment: This proof by contradiction is a thin wrapper around a direct proof. If $g(0) = 0$ then we are done; otherwise $g(0) = -g(1/2)$ shows $g(0)$ and $g(1/2)$ have opposite sign and we can apply the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @JansonA.J thank you, the explanation is clear. What I was thinking is that, if I can define a function say $p:\mathbb{R}  \to S^1$ then the composition $f \circ p :S^1 \to S^1$ which is an identity on $S^1$ . Since the identity function is bijective, it required that $f$ be surjective and $p$ injective. I guess this reasonoing is flawed.

Comment: @RicardoBuring Yes yes, that's true.

Answer (score 6):

You can parameterize $S^1$ in the usual way, so that $f$ is a function from $[0,2\pi]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with $f(0)=f(2\pi)$.

Then define $g(x):[0,\pi]\to\mathbb{R}$, $g(x) = f(x+\pi)-f(x)$.

1. How does $g(0)$ relate to $g(\pi)$?
2. What can you conclude from the intermediate value theorem?

Comment: $g(0)=f(\pi)-f(o)$ and $g(\pi)=f(2\pi)-f(\pi)=f(0)-f(\pi)=-(f(\pi)-f(o))$ So, $g(0)=-g(\pi)$

Comment: Yes. Can you take it from here, or do you need more hints?

Comment: okay, as $g(\pi)<0<g(0)$ or the other way.. So, by intermediate value theorem there exists $a\in [0,\pi]$ such that $g(a)=0$ i.e., $f(a+\pi)=f(a)$

Comment: can i then say $f(a+\pi)=f(-a)$ ???

Comment: $f(a)$ and $f(a+\pi)$ are antipodal points on the circle, so if $f(a) = f(a+\pi)$ you are done.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik Yes, because we can parametrize $S^1$ by $e^{i \theta} \rightarrow f(\theta)$, so $f(a+\pi ) = e^{i(a+\pi )} = -f(a)$.

Comment: @AndrewD : yes yes.. i got it.. Thank you

Comment: @user7530 ok, Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $\alpha:[0,1]\to S^1$ parametrize the unit circle, and take $g(z)=f(z)-f(-z)$. Apply the Intermediate Value Theorem to $g\circ\alpha$.

Second hint: If $\alpha(a)=1$ and $\alpha(b)=-1$, analyze $g\circ\alpha(a)$ and $g\circ\alpha(b)$.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to expand on what Quickbeam2k1 wrote at the top -  <strike>while he's not 100% right (it isn't clear from this particular example that there exist two antipodal points on earth with the same temperature),</strike>  (he is indeed correct, as he pointed out) he's leading you to the right conclusion - that this phenomena you described in your question happens to generalize to higher dimensions. If you're interested, you should look at the [wikipedia page for the Borsuk-Ulam theorem,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem) which I think is exactly what Quickbeam2k1 is leading you towards.

Comment: But on the equator this should be correct? The same should hold on the circles of latitude and longitude. Or am i false there? Of course Borsuk's theorem fits better to the earth :)

Comment: Ah, i misunderstood - you are completely correct about the equators you mentioned, but I thought it was still worth mentioning the Borsuk-Ulam lemma.