# How to prove the existence of such an $x \in S^{1}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Consider this problem :

> Let $S^{1}  =\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \mid x^2 +y^2 =1\}$. Let $f: S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Prove that there exits $x\in S^1$ such that $f(x)=f(-x)$.

I am not able to construct such a function and I am not getting any ideas on which result I should use for construction.

Can you please help me with that?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492599/f-s1-to-mathbb-r-is-continuous-then-fx-f-x-for-some-x-in-s1

Comment: "I am not able to construct such a function" What? Literally every continuous function has this property.