# Proving $S^1$ is not homeomorphic to any subset $A\subset \mathbb R$

Tags: general-topology

Let $\phi : S^1 \to A$ be an homeomorphism while $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$.

Then by [fixed point theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492599/f-s1-to-mathbb-r-is-continuous-then-fx-f-x-for-some-x-in-s1), there exists at least one element satisfying $\phi(-x)=\phi(x)$, i.e $\phi$ is not injective, which is contradiction.

Do you see any problem with this proof?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this proof it seems fine to me as long as the fixed point theorem doesn't somehow use this fact in its proof (which I don't believe it does), so I think you are fine

Comment: If $\phi$ where a homeomorphism, then $A$ must be a compact interval, but compact interval is not homogeneous. Contradiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only objection I can imagine to using the fixed point theorem to prove this result would be that it is a somewhat heavy hammer to use in order to prove the statement you need. For example, $S^1$ is compact and connected, and hence if $\phi\colon S^1 \to \mathbb R$ is continuous, its image is also compact and connected and hence (since connected subsets of $\mathbb R$ are intervals and compact subsets are closed and bounded subsets of $\mathbb R$) $A = \phi(S^1) = [a,b]$ for some $a\leq b \in \mathbb R$.

But now $a<b$ since otherwise the cardinality of $\phi(S^1)$ is finite, and so $\phi$ would fail to be injective. But then if $a<c<b$ then $[a,b]\backslash\{c\}$ is not connected, whereas if $p\in S^1$ is any point on the circle, $S^1\backslash \{p\}$ is connected. But if $\phi\colon S^1 \to [a,b]$ was a homeomorphism and we set $p=\phi^{-1}(c)$, then it would restrict to a homeomorphism between $S^1\backslash \{p\}$ and $[a,b]\backslash \{c\}$, and hence as connectedness is a topological property, we have a contradiction.

Comment: +1 Don´t You mean $[a,b]\backslash \{\phi(p)\}$?

Comment: Thanks for the details! It helped me a lot :)

Comment: @PeterMelech Thanks for querying this -- the key is to remove a point $p$ from the circle whose image is a point in the interior of $[a,b]$, so what I failed to say was that I wanted $\phi(p)=c$ (or $p=\phi^{-1}(c)$). I hope everything is clear now!

Comment: @krm2233 very clear and a very clear answer!